# Origin of message from Xlib: "Killed"

Tags: linux, xlib

I'm using ImLib2 to grab images periodically from an Xlib application; and sending fake keysignals to the application window using libxdo. After about 10 minutes, my command-line program terminates with the message "Killed".

I'm quite new to X programming. Does anyone know where the "Killed" message is being sent from?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Enable `core` dumps (maybe with `ulimit -c`). If you get such a dump, do a post mortem analysis using the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been due to not calling the `imlib_free_image` function after each call to `imlib_context_set_image`. The inner loop now looks more like this:

```
Imlib_Image ii = imlib_create_image_from_drawable(0,x,y,w,h,1);
imlib_context_set_image(ii);
DATA32 *data = imlib_image_get_data();
examine_data(data);
imlib_free_image();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you launch your command-line program with a trailing "&" to put it in the background?  If so, you probably need to also do a "nohup" before the command.  Assuming your program is called grab.sh, you should probably invoke it like this:

```
nohup grab.sh &
```

If you do a

```
echo TMOUT is $TMOUT
```

and see

```
TMOUT is 600
```

then what is happening is your terminal session where you invoked the command is getting killed after `$TMOUT` seconds of inactivity, killing your process.  The `nohup` command will prevent your process from being killed.

Comment: Alas no, I run it in the foreground without the &. I hadn't hear of nohup before though, so I'll try it anyway...